# jQuery weird error with tumblr api

Tags: jquery, tumblr

This code works and outputs the posts correctly, but then it throws the error function I specified. Can't figure out why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
  writeData = function(data)
  {      
      $.each(data.response.posts, function() {
      $('<div class="post"></div>')
        .hide()
        .append('<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>')
        .append('<p>' + this.body + '</p>')
        .appendTo('#posts')
        .fadeIn()
      });
  }

  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url : "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myBlog.tumblr.com/posts?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      error: function() {
        alert('an error occurred!');
      },
      data: {
          api_key : "api Key here",
          //limit : "1",
          jsonp : "writeData"
      }

  });

});
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: nope, nothing in the console. should i just remove the error function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the error function since, technically, JSONP requests shouldn't be using that handler at all. Only the most recent versions of jQuery (1.5.2 and up, it looks like) actually support  error handling with JSONP requests and according to the several bug reports that I found on the topic, it's spotty at best.